# selecting only some facets to print in facet_wrap, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

my question is very simple, but I have failed to solve it after many attempts. I just want to print some facets of a facetted plot (made with facet_wrap in ggplot2), and remove the ones I am no interested in.

I have facet_wrap with ggplot2, as follows:

```
#anomalies linear trends
an.trends <- ggplot()+
  geom_smooth(method="lm", data=tndvilong.anomalies, aes(x=year, y=NDVIan, colour=TenureZone,
                                                     group=TenureZone))+
  scale_color_manual(values=miscol) + 
  ggtitle("anomalies' trends")

#anomalies linear trends by VEG
an.trendsVEG <- an.trends + facet_wrap(~VEG,ncol=2)
print(an.trendsVEG)
```

And I get the plot as I expected (you can see it in te link below):

[anomalies' trends by VEG](http://s17.postimg.org/qc0op4gwv/anomalies_trends_by_veg.png)

The question is: how do I get printed only the facest I am interested on? 
I only want to print "CenKal_ShWoodl", "HlShl_ShDens", "NKal_ShWoodl", and "ThShl_ShDens"

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest the easiest way to do that is to simply give `ggplot()` an appropriate subset. In this case:

```
facets <- c("CenKal_ShWoodl", "HlShl_ShDens", "NKal_ShWoodl", "ThShl_ShDens")
an.trends.sub <- ggplot(tndvilong.anomalies[tndvilong.anomalies$VEG %in% facets,])+
  geom_smooth(method="lm" aes(x=year, y=NDVIan, colour=TenureZone,
                                                     group=TenureZone))+
  scale_color_manual(values=miscol) + 
  ggtitle("anomalies' trends") +
  facet_wrap(~VEG,ncol=2)
```

Obviously without your data I can't be sure this will give you what you want, but based on your description, it should work. I find that with ggplot, it is generally best to pass it the data you want plotted, rather than finding ways of changing the plot itself.

Comment: This really works perfect, really thankful. Now I am trying to include the R^2 value for each line in the plots, so I can compare how different the tendencies are. All the solutions I am finding in the web suggest to calculate the equation and add the results to a dataset to plot them after. I wonder if ggplot2 does not have an argument just to simply add this information.

Comment: I'd say if all the solutions you found are telling you the same thing, there's a message there... but either way, sounds like a separate question to me - don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem